# How to obtain a working X509Certificate for my WCF Service hosting

Tags: .net, wcf-security, x509certificate

I am in the process of hosting my WCF services in my asp.net hosting account and I want to use X509Certificate for authentication of communication. Where do I get a certificate in this instance? Make one and then Ftp it to my account? If yes, how do I reference this certificate for use. If No, how do I get one for use please? Do I need to purchase one or something?

---

I can create and install one on my local machine, but asking of how I would go about doing that on a hosting machine somewhere that I do not have remote access to, just FTP access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can purchase one from companies like VeriSign, or you can make it one on your own if you install a Certification Authority (CA) service on a windows server machine that release a certificate for your WCF.

Certificate have to be installed in your application, i did it for a web application and it's quite simple with the IIS management tool.